# Laravel eloquent api resource remove `data` key (no collection)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have custom eloquent api resource for `user`. For example when I use this resource

**Code**

```
$user = $request->user();
return new UserResource($user);
```

Then on response I get:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Margarete Daniel",
        "email": "goldner.berniece@example.net",
        "verified": "2020-03-20T07:15:56.000000Z"
    }
}
```

How I can change api resource and get example response:

```
{
    "name": "Margarete Daniel",
    "email": "goldner.berniece@example.net",
    "verified": "2020-03-20T07:15:56.000000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can disable data wrapping by calling the `withoutWrapping` static method of your resource in the `AppServiceProvider`. In your case it will be:

```php
public function boot()
{
    UserResource::withoutWrapping();
}
```

You can refer to [Laravel documentation about data wrapping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping) for more explanation.

Answer (score 56):

Add this to your resource

```
public static $wrap = null;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - this disables the data wrapping per resource rather than the entire application

Answer (score 23):

Answering as I keep stumbling on the same problem myself.

The easiest way to return a Laravel resource without the `data` wrap is to simply return it in a JSON response. So instead of doing:

```
return new UserResource($user);
```

You would do:

```
return response()->json(new UserResource($user));
```

This way you also don't have to worry about stuffing your `AppServiceProvider` with a lot of calls to the `withoutWrapping` method.

Comment: Why returning JsonResponse removes the wrap? Any link to documentation?

Comment: @rock3t If you convert a resource to a JsonResponse manually (like the example above), JsonResponse assumes that there is always a $data property in the resource and uses it like `$resource->data`. That's why the unwrapping only happens when the resource is translated into the response by itself. i.e. `return new UserResource($user);`

Answer (score 17):

To remove the data wrapper for **all** resources inside your project just add:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource    

public function boot()
{
    JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
}
```

Inside the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Answer (score 10):

this worked for me

```
return UserResource::make($user)->toArray($request);
```

and for collection

```
return UserResource::collection($users)->collection;
```

Answer (score 5):

For some reason this works:

```php
$user = User::find(1);

return UserResource::make($user)->resolve();
```

Without `->resolve()` it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who need to remove the wrapper on an ad-hoc basis (like using Inertia props), you can set the wrapper to null.

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail(10);
$commentData = new CommentResource($comment);
$commentData->wrap(null);
return Inertia::render('Comment/Show', [
    'myExtraPropDatum' => 'extra_data',
    'comment' => $commentData,
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MainBannerResource extends JsonResource
{
    public static $wrap = null;

    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

write `public static $wrapp = null;` for resource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Removing the data key without globally removing it

Answer (score 2):

inside your resource file, at the **toArray()** method, override the parent $wrap

```
 public function toArray(Request $request): array
     {
            parent::wrap(null); 
            return [' enter code here'];
     }
```

Comment: All the other solutions didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

use JsonResource::withoutWrapping(); or DeviceResource::withoutWrapping();
in your controller just before the response line

```
JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
return $this->response(JsonResource::make($reportArray),JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
```

This way it will affect only your current resource response otherwise it will affect other responses too.
If you want to wrap it in any other key you may use

```
JsonResource::wrap('reportData');
```

and it will use this key instead of data. Also you may add `static $wrap = null`; in the resource, file to avoid the data key.